# GeometryReader unwanted full height/width behaviour

Tags: swiftui

I'm using the `GeometryReader` for making sure that an image is never wider than half of the screen's width. However, it messes up the rest of my view as the `GeometryReader` requests the full height/width of the View (as shown in the image with the green BG). As if it inserts unwanted `Spacer()`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack {
                GeometryReader{ g in
                    HStack{
                        Text("Text Left").background(Color.yellow)
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)
                            .frame(maxWidth: g.size.width/2)
                    }.background(Color.yellow)
                }.background(Color.green)
            }
            Text("Bottom Text")

            // This Spacer should push the "Bottom Text" right below the other Text and Image
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If I remove the `GeometryReader` and set the width to a fixed size, it works as expected and the green BG does not show up.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    Text("Text Left").background(Color.yellow)
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)
                        .frame(maxWidth: 200)
                }.background(Color.yellow)
            }.background(Color.green)
            Text("Bottom Text")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or how can the dynamic width be achieved with the `GeometryReader`?

[image]

Comment: All is as expected. GeometryReader consumes all available space of proposed by parent container, so as in your case only bottom Text has defined size, it's fixed, everything else consumed by GeometryReader. Spacer always consumes *remaining* space (actually by having own GeometryReader inside), so in this case nothing, as it is last. No magic. All what you were needed is `UIScreen.main.bounds`. GeometryReader is for different purposes.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. `UIScreen.main.bounds` works for this example only partly. If the device is turned to landscape, it doesn't consider the new width (`GeometryReader` does however).

Comment: As soon as one has multiple nested Views, `GeometyReader` produces unexpected layouts IMO. Do you have an idea, how I can use `GeometryReader` in a child component without using all available space from the parent view?

Comment: Did overcome this issue? Do you know any possible workarounds?

Answer (score 5):

You can use GeometryReader with a clear background element and save the size as a @State object since background() won't mess with the layout but still compute the full layout size:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero // "proxy" size

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello World")
                .frame(minWidth: contentSize.width) // use here
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear
                            .onAppear {
                                contentSize = geometry.size
                            }
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

This effectively work in any subview.

I found this solution with this article:
https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/01/15/the-magic-of-view-preferences-in-swiftui/

Comment: For some reason, there was still some unwanted height in my case. The issue was fixed after using `@State private var contentSize: CGSize? = nil` instead and passing nil to `.frame(width: width)`. ```var width: CGFloat? {
        if let contentSize {
            return contentSize.width / 3.5
        }
        return nil
    }```

Answer (score 2):

why do you set the geometryreader inside vstack? maybe you have a reason...but this way, i think, works as you want it?!

But yeah, you are right, the thing with the geometryreader is weird...

```
 GeometryReader{ g in

            VStack{
                VStack {
                    HStack{
                        Text("Text Left").background(Color.yellow)
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode:.fit)
                            .frame(maxWidth: g.size.width/2)
                            .background(Color.red)
                    }.background(Color.yellow)

                }
                Text("Bottom Text")

                // This Spacer should push the "Bottom Text" right below the other Text and Image
                Spacer()
            }
        }.background(Color.green)
```

Comment: My layout is more complex than this example with many nested views. Thus, I need it inside a child view and not as the outer most view 

Comment: ah ok...didn't know that.